# Помогите реализовать горизонтальный скролл

Tags: javascript, jquery, вёрстка, frontend

Есть header, высотой 100vh, на всю ширину. И есть два aside, с независимым скроллом, которые находятся за пределами видимости слева и справа соответственно. При наведении мыши на левую или правую часть хедера (20%) плавно выдвигаются соответственно слева или справа эти aside, сдвигая хедер. [Вот так](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0s91ecfomiwbgj9/01_Home.mov?dl=0). Как можно это реализовать, подскажите, пожалуйста. Эксперименты с transform: translateX приводят к дёрганью экрана (вешаю события на mouseover и mouseout). Может, есть какой-то готовый плагин для этой вещи? Я просто не знаю даже, по какому запросу искать в гугле.

Comment: Вставьте минимальный код в вопрос, иначе на него сложно или невозможно будет ответить.

Comment: @labris В вопросе есть ссылка, **как** это должно быть реализовано. Мои методы реализации не срабатывают, но, говорят, в сети полно плагинов для этого. Я даже не знаю, каким образом сформировать запрос в гугле, чтобы реализовать эту задачу.

Comment: Я бы подумала в сторону анимации на jquery, на те же события. Если Вы нашли ответ на свой вопрос, поделитесь пожалуйста, как решили задачу, хотя бы в двух словах - интересно же